# What are the individual directx components for wine?

Tags: wine, 64-bit, 19.10, winetricks

I am trying to install directx on wine, so I ran `winetricks directx9` in terminal. Here is the output:

```
------------------------------------------------------
You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20190912 - sha256sum: 669617710f27ac714338ad98a6ae90034d41e05b697dd9489b190b65e2b824b7 with wine-4.0.2 (Ubuntu 4.0.2-1) and WINEARCH=win64
Executing w_do_call directx9
Executing load_directx9 
------------------------------------------------------
directx9 is deprecated. Please install individual directx components (e.g., `/usr/bin/winetricks d3dx9`) instead.
------------------------------------------------------
You opted in, so reporting 'directx9 ' to the winetricks maintainer so he knows which winetricks verbs get used and which don't.  Use --optout to disable future reports.
```

So what do I need to install instead of directx? Is it only `d3dx9` or other things too?